# Problem on the density of $P[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

How can I show that the space of polynomials on $[0,1]$i.e,$P[0,1]$ is dense in $L^1[0,1]$ but not in $C[0,1]$?

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: What denotes $P$ ?

Comment: probably polynomials, I have a question, is the norm in $C[0,1]$ the supremum norm?

Comment: Isn't the fact that $P[0,1]$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ the stone-weierstrass theorem?

Comment: @ Jorge Fernández Hidalgo:but that holds for sup norms .I have given $L^1$ norm

Comment: @vikash $\|\cdot\|_{L^1}≤\|\cdot\|_\infty$ so if $p_n\to f$ in sup norm so also  in $L^1$ norm and $P$ is dense in $C$ with this norm also.

Comment: Aside from that since $C[0,1]$ is obviously a subspace of $L^1[0,1]$ if given the $L^1$ norm, $P$ being dense in $L^1$ implies $P$ being dense in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: @s.harp: thanks...now i get it